# Linked lists implementation issue

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, allocation

I'm trying to make a Stack using an underlying linked list structure.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I'm having trouble with the remove() function.

```
int Stack::remove(){  
  node* victim = new node;  
  int popped;  
  popped = top->element;  
  victim = top;
  top = victim->next;  
  delete victim;  
  return popped;  
}
```

I'm getting glibc dectecting

> double free or corruption (out);

Since I'm allocating new memory with victim, don't I have to delete victim, or is that something I don't have to worry about?

Comment: No point in allocating memory or using new for the victim node.  Remember a pointer is simply a reference, so just have it point to the head of the list.  Save the data value, move the head of the list to the next element (may want to check for NULL) and then delete the temp pointer that you originally had pointing to head.  That means you've popped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack is much like a bunch of dishes that are being washed and set on top of one another.  That is the first one in is the last one out (FILO data type).  That is if your stack read in 2, 7, 8 then it would appear as :

8

7

2

That is first the 2 is placed in the stack, followed by the 7 and then by the 8.  If you want to remove or pop the stack you need to move the head of the pointer.  Your code looks a bit strange to me...

```
int Stack::remove()
 {
  int datum;      //to store the popped value
  node* temp=head;  //assign pointer to head of list
  datum = temp->data; //grab the data value stored at the head (or temp since they carry same reference)
  head = temp->next; //move the head pointer (in our example now it points to 7)
  delete temp;
  return datum;
 }
```

Comment: You may want to throw in some error checking to check for nulls.

Comment: shouldnt temp->next be set to null because some people create custom destructors so that if a node is deleted, it deletes recursively the node it points to

Comment: @Jaelebi no as temp is deleted, look closely at the implementation as temp just temporarily becomes the head of the list.  Head is moved and then temp is deallocated using delete.  You could say `temp->next=NULL;` right before 'delete temp;` but considering that you are deleting it and the function ends it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to allocate heap memory in a `remove()` method as you are doing with `victim`. What you want is:

```
int Stack::remove(){  
  node* new_top = top->next;
  int popped = top->element;

  delete top;  
  top = new_top;

  return popped;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to allocate a node for `victim`. Just assign the top of the stack to it and, if it's not `null`, set `top` to its `next` pointer, retrieve the value from `victim`, and then deallocate the `victim`.

It's not actually a corruption, but a memory leak - you are allocating a node, and then override that pointer with `victim = top;` thus losing track of just allocated memory.